# Very strange biblatex style in french archeology

Tags: biblatex, babel, small-caps, french

I have many problems with a bibliography style with `biblatex`. And excuse my english, I'm a French student.

I would like a style like this:

[image]

but after a lot of research I obtained:

[image]

It is almost perfect but I do not manage to obtain the key in small letters, doubtless because of the `babel` package with the `french` option which puts the authors in small capitals.
After the key is sometimes stupid like that :

[image]

Finally I would like to remove the quotation marks of the title of article like this journal ! (for curious it's [Documents d'Archéologie Méridionales (external link)](http://dam.revues.org) )

Here are the modifications that I made in the stoneware of my researches on the Internet in my preamble and a short extract of my bibliography:

```
    @BOOK{bohec95,
    title = {Histoire militaire des guerres puniques},
  publisher = {{\'E}dition du Rocher},
  year = {1995},
  author = {Le Bohec, Yann},
  address = {Monaco},
  entrysubtype = {sources secondaires},
  keywords = {monographie, histoire},
  lccn = {96141557},
  owner = {Axel},
  pagetotal = {337},
  timestamp = {2013.09.25}
}

@ARTICLE{leveau03,
  author = {{\relax Ph}ilippe Leveau},
  title = {Le franchissement du Rh\^one par Hannibal : le chenal et la navigation
    fluviale à la fin de l'\^Age du Fer},
  journal = {Revue archéologique},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {3},
  pages = {25-50},
  number = {35},
  entrysubtype = {sources secondaires},
    keywords = {article, histoire},
  owner = {Axel},
  shortjournal = {RA},
  timestamp = {2013.09.25}
}

    \documentclass{article} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRANCAIS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[french]{babel}


\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %BILIOGRAPHIE  

\usepackage[                                                                                                                %BILIOGRAPHIE
  backend=bibtex,bibstyle=authortitle,citestyle=authoryear,sorting=nyt
                                % Configuration de la bilio
]{biblatex} 


\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxnames=3, % Et al. quand trop de nom
firstinits=true,
uniquename=init%initiale
}                                                           
%% BIDOUILLES BIBLIO

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\parentext{#1}}                                           %parenthèse de l'initiale
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}                                                                     %rangement des noms de famille et prénoms
\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{\addnbspace}                                                 %Enlève la virgule après le nom de famille quand nom inversé
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addnbspace\addcomma\addnbspace}                 %   remplace et par ","
 \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addnbspace\addcomma\addnbspace}                %   remplace et par ","

 \DeclareLabelname{%
\field{editor}
}



\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
 \printtext{\bfseries{\printnames{labelname}}\space\printfield{year}\space\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printtext{\bfseries{\printnames{labelname}}\space\printfield{year}\space\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
   \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
     {\printfield{issn}}
     {}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
   \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{pageref}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \iftoggle{bbx:related}
     {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
      \usebibmacro{related}}
     {}%
   \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printtext{\bfseries{\printnames{labelname}}\space\printfield{year}\space\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
 \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printtext{\bfseries{\printnames{labelname}}\space\printfield{year}\space\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


% "Et al." en ITALIQUE

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

%Enlever le tiret lorsqu'il y a une récurrence des auteurs
%
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extrayear}}
\makeatother

%Enlever les parenthèses des dates des articles
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% NEW
%  \printtext[parens]{% DELETED
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
%       \usebibmacro{date}}}% DELETED
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

%Met les abréviations des revues
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {%
      \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
        {}
        {%
          \printtext[journaltitle]
            {%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
              \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}%
             }%
         }%
    }
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}%
    }
```

Bigs modifications are with this line for dash and key.

```
 \printtext{\bfseries{\printnames{labelname}}\space\printfield{year}\space\addcolon\space}%
```

*Voilà!* (I always dreamed to write in italics :p)

If somebody has an idea I would be extremely happy and delighted in others it would be awesome ! :D
Thanks a lot. 
Merci beaucoup.

EDIT: Yeah there are others problems with the field editor, there is "sous la direction de" and I would like "dir." after the author like that:
[image]

After how to change the citation in lower case with authoryear style?

Finally I can't use Linux Libertine with this style because I always have smalls caps, do you have a solution?

Edit2 : Wonderful ! It's almost perfect ! You're a genius ! :D Indeed, i can use xelatex and have some fancy ligatures with linux libertine :)

For "et al." I would like in label not in the list of author.
[image]
Informal in this journal sometimes we have "et al." in the key and sometimes no, like with the previous example with Py,Lopez,Asensio. I don't understand.

The ultimate edit :

I succeed  to have "dir." instead "éd" and "Établit par" for ancients sources with that :

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
 byeditor = \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}% %Etablit par, pour les sources et dir. pour les inX
 {Établit\space par}%
{dir\adddotspace\smartof}, 
 editor           = {dir.},
 editors          = {dir.},
}
```

But I have a annoying comma after the author.!
[image]
Do you have an idea to remove this ?

I'm seeing another problems... For page of books I use "pagetotal" to have : 550 p. for example, so with your code I have a final dot. Ok. But I have a dot after the date too. And with article, I don't have final dot thanks to :

```
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
```

So, how do I do, to have always a final dot, but a comma after date because for the moment I have this:

[image]

I succeed to remove the comma before "dir.", and parenthesis for proceedings, there is only this problem of dot after date and put byeditor before maintitle.

Last edit : I managed to remove the point after the date and change the order of entries inbook, incollection etc. in by  modifying the order in the file standard.

Here is my last one MWE for futures generations ! XD

```
\usepackage[                                                                                                                %BILIOGRAPHIE
  backend=bibtex,style=authoryear, firstinits, mergedate=false, style=authoryear-ibid,maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=999
                                % Configuration de la bilio
]{biblatex} 

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\parentext{#1}}                   %parenthèse de l'initiale

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\space\textendash\space}      %tiret après le label



\renewbibmacro*{date+extrayear}{}%                                          rajoute date

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1}

  \renewbibmacro{in:}{%                                                                 enlève guillemets articles
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

    \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printdate%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace\addcolon\space}}

  %Met les abréviations des revues
\renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
  \iffieldundef{shortjournal}
    {%
      \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
        {}
        {%
          \printtext[journaltitle]
            {%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}%
              \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
              \printfield[titlecase]{journalsubtitle}%
             }%
         }%
    }
    {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{shortjournal}}}%
}

%Enlever le tiret lorsqu'il y a une récurrence des auteurs
%
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extrayear}}
\makeatother

% "Et al." en ITALIQUE

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}%
     \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

 %%% Histoire des noms    et al...
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{##1}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \printtext[bold]{\usebibmacro{cite}\addspace:\space}%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxbibnames}
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{\textnohyphenation{##1}}}}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{#1}}                 %minuscule citation

\renewbibmacro*{event+venue+date}{                        %Enlève parenthèse colloque
  \iffieldundef{eventtitle}
    {}
    {%
      \bibstring{presentedat}%
      \printfield{eventtitle}%
    }%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{venue}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{eventyear}}
  }
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \printtext{%
       \printfield{venue}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
       \printeventdate}}%
  \newunit
}


    \DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%
 byeditor = \iffieldequalstr{keywords}{source}%                         %Etablit par, pour les sources et dir. pour les inX
 {Établit\space par}%
{dir\adddotspace\smartof}, 
in = {\textit{in}},%
 editor           = {dir\adddotspace},%
 editors          = {dir\adddotspace},%
 opcit = \iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{article}{art\adddotspace cit\adddot}{\emph{op\adddotspace cit}\adddot},%
idem = {\emph{idem}},%
ibidem = {\emph{ibid\adddot}},%
%pagetotal = {p\adddot},%
 %pages            = {pp\adddot},%
}
%enlève la virugule avant dir.
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
%   \setunit{\addcomma\space}% DELETED
    \setunit{\addspace}% ADDED
    \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
%     \usebibmacro{#1}% DELETED
     \printtext{\usebibmacro{#1}}% ADDED
     \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
\makeatother
 %%modifié book pour virgule
 \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\addcomma
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

  %Change ordre des entrées pour les in quelquechoses : 
  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
 \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others}%
  \setunit{\space\textendash\space}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock   
\usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

I a

Comment: I already asked this question for you and had a quite satisfying answer. Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155812/modifying-alphabetic-biblabels-with-biblatex It only remains to make a few modifications to fulfill all of the requirements. Sorry for not having passed this answer on sooner.

Comment: Ah cool, c'est super ! Mais je ne comprend pas pourquoi il faut passer sur d'autre paquet notamment

Comment: ah zut plus le temps ...
notamment ceux là ?
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

Après j'ai d'autre soucis, comment mettre à la place de "sous la direction de" pour les éditeurs un (dir.) après l'auteur? Et lorsqu'on cite avec \parentcite pourquoi ça ne met pas la clé en minuscule mais en petites capitales?

Merci beaucoup

Comment: En fait, mon problème de capitale venait de Linux Libertine... Je viens de m'en rendre compte en bidouillant les polices.

Comment: Could you solve your problem with Bernard's link, or is there anything else you need to have done?

Comment: It is unlikely that only Linux Libertine causes small caps in your output as the French language file for `biblatex`, namely `french.lbx`, defines `\mkbibnamelast` to use small caps.  Can you provide a font where, with everything else the same, the output is not in small caps.

Comment: In fact, with some font there is small caps like : \usepackage{fourier}, mathptmx or mathpazo whereas with aeguill it's ok. I don't understand

Comment: I thought, using your code for the begentry macro and specifying values for mincitenames and maxcitenames in the preamble, that the labels would use the "et al." formulation in case there are, say, 3 or more authors, while the authors  list would contain all the authors. It didn't work. Did I miss something?

Comment: Regarding the number of names, please have a look at my edited answer in [Modifying alphabetic biblabels with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155908/35864). Maybe you would like to edit your question to use the solution in the answer there and *then* ask additional questions (feel free to take the MWE there).

Comment: @Bernard I have modified my answer to the other question slightly to deal with the name number thingy. What do you think.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do no really understand your trouble with "et al." truncations. Currently it should work as follows: List of up to three authors are never truncated; lists with more than three are truncated in the label (i.e in citations) and in the introductory label part of the bibliography, not the author list itself. This seems the most natural to me, it would seem to odd to omit the "et al" in citations or the bold part.

Comment: Oups sorry ! It works ! I didn't understand, now I do ! Thanks you so much

Comment: @moewe: Your modification works fine, thanks a lot. I only had to replace, in the re-definition of "begentry", the \textsc command with \MakeUppercase in order to satisfy the requirement of the journal. I also tested it with an inbook item and modified the "bybookauthor" macro so that it adds ", éd." after the name of the bookauthor. However the separator (just before the book title) has to be an endash, and I only know how to achieve this by changing one line in the bibliography driver. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @Bernard I suppose one could use `xpatch` again to avoid having to copy-and-paste the whole driver into the document. Is the order of fields right in `@inbook` and friends? From what I gather it should be "Ditor, Eddie (ed) -- Title", but standard `biblatex` is "Title, edited by Eddie Ditor".

Comment: @axelito: I have a solution for the problems of punctuation, using xpatch (thanks  @moewe!) and am curently cleaning the the code.

Comment: Ah cool ! Je pédalais dans la semoule là !

Comment: See also (but without the explicit reference to French in the question) [Changing default \citet font in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53309/35864)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> À propos du problème des noms d'auteurs en petites capitale, on peut dire à frenchb (module de babel pour le français) de ne pas adopter ce comportement en ajoutant la ligne suivante au préambule.

Regarding the problem of author names in small capital, one can tell `frenchb` (the `babel` module for French) not to do it by adding the following line to the preamble (after the call of babel and biblatex):

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
```

Comment: AFAICS, it should now be `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}`