# Setting [frenchb]{babel} with biblatex puts author names in small capitals. How to get back to first letter capitalized?

Tags: biblatex, babel, french

I am confused by the way the authors' names are capitalized when both biblatex and frenchb in bbel are used. There is no reference to this behavior in either documentation and I don't know how to make the authors' names appear as in the "english" style.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt]{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\input{glyphtounicode}   %  to enable ligatured letters
\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
    \usepackage{fontenc}

\PassOptionsToPackage{frenchb,english}{babel}
    \usepackage{babel}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{frenchpro}{babel} % inopérant

\frenchbsetup{LowercaseSuperscripts=false}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\PassOptionsToPackage{%
    %backend=biber, %instead of bibtex
    backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
    %language=autobib,%
    language=auto,
    %language=french,
    %autocite=inline,
    %style=numeric-comp,%
    style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
    %style=authoryear,%
    %style=alphabetic,%
    %bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
    sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
    maxbibnames=3, % default: 3, et al.
    backref=true,%
    hyperref=true,
    natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still     work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
%\addbibresource{../Xbib.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{abr4,
  Title                    = {Bargaining, reputation and equilibrium     selection in repeated games with contracts},
  Author                   = {Dilip Abreu and David Pearce},
  Journal                  = {Econometrica},
  Year                     = {2007},
  Number                   = {3},
  Pages                    = {653-710},
  Volume                   = {75},
}
@InBook{bar3,
   Title                    = {Mathematical theory of reliability},
  Author                   = {Richard E. Barlow and Frank Proschan},
  Chapter                  = {1},
  Pages                    = {9-18},
  Publisher                = {{J}ohn {W}iley \& {S}ons},
  Year                     = {1965}
 }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{french} % if commented, authors appear with only first letter capitalized
\section{First section}
  This is a document.
  I cite a book here: \cite{bar3}. An article here:\cite{abr4}.

  \printbibliography 
 \end{document}
```

As you can see when comment out "selectlanguage=french", the names come with a first capital : Barlow and Proschan. When selectlanguage is set to french, we get BARLOW, Richard E. and Franck PROSCHAN.

It would be OK if the capital letters only appeared in the reference section. But I find it awkward that in the text the authorname also appears in CAPITALS.
Any work around?
Thanks.

Comment: Does `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{#1}}` help? This is implemented in the French localisation files (that is probably why the manual does not mention it), apparently someone thought it is good French standard (and from what I have seen it is common in French texts).

Comment: See also [Very strange biblatex style in french archeology](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156857/35864) and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/N2gfzWYTkAo

Comment: Since the question is resolved and the solution is essentially the same as in [Very strange biblatex style in french archeology](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156857/35864) would you mind if we were to mark your question as a duplicate?

Comment: I have found the nicer duplicate [Changing default \citet font in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53309/35864)

Answer (score 4):

YES! This corrects this apparently French quirk of capitalizing authors' names even when citing them between parentheses.
So the right command to add to the preamble after loading biblatex is:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\renewcommand*\mkbibnamelast[1]{#1}}
```