# Citations in small caps using Biblatex in french (APA style)

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, french

I have a small issue while using Biblatex with the APA style in French. My in-text citations are in small caps and I would like to have them written normally. This issue doesn't happen when I write in English.

Can someone help me?

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
\DeclareCaseLangs{french}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}

Cette référence: \textcite{Kline2016} s'affiche en majuscules.

\end{document}
```

This will produce "Cette référence: KLINE (2016) s'affiche en majuscules" and I would like to have "Cette référence: Kline (2016) s'affiche en majuscules".

Thanks!

Comment: `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}` (or with older versions `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamelast}`)

Comment: See also [Very strange biblatex style in french archeology](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156704/35864), [Changing default \citet font in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53309/35864) where the answers say `\mkbibnamelast` because they were written before `biblatex` 3.3 (see [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864))

Comment: @moewe: Not sure if I understand well what you suggestion does, but doesn't it affect also the names in the references section?

Comment: @Bernard Yes that is true. I didn't think the OP would want to change the behaviour in citations only. In that case `\AtEveryCite{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of small caps in citations only, or do you want them gone in the bibliography as well?

Comment: @moewe, the bibliography was fine so no need to change it. I just tested your solution and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: I assume you meant my second solution? I have written up an answer with it. If you mean my first comment, please get back to me, I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the style only for in-text citations use

```
\AtEveryCite{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}
```