# Finalnamedelim is not working in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, babel, delimiters

I have problems with the `\finalnamedelim` when I use the `babel` package.

As you can see in this example I only get `;` separator without the `babel` package.

So, what is the right way in this case?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{book}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@Article{Kenawy2015,
    Title                    = {Conjunctival squamous cell neoplasia: the Liverpool Ocular Oncology Centre experience},
    Author                   = {Kenawy, N. and Garrick, A. and Heimann, H. and Coupland, SE. and Damato, BE.},
    Journal                  = {Graefes Arch Clin Exp Ophthalmol},
    Year                     = {2015},
    Pages                    = {43--50},
    Volume                   = {253},
}

@Article{Pantanowitz2008,
    Title                    = {Kaposi sarcoma in unusual locations},
    Author                   = {Pantanowitz, L. and Dezube, BJ.},
    Journal                  = {BMC Cancer},
    Year                     = {2008},
    Pages                    = {1--9},
    Volume                   = {8},
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,ibidtracker=false,maxbibnames=100,maxcitenames=2,hyperref=true,backend=biber,isbn=false,sorting=ydnt,sortcites=true,labelalpha,maxalphanames=1,doi=false,dashed=false,urldate=long,block=space,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{} 

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [Very strange biblatex style in french archeology](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156704/35864). But the connection is only really visible if you know the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spanish.lbx` contains some fancy code for a 'smart and' to properly typeset the 'and' in Spanish. If you want to get around that you will need

```
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}{%
  \restorecommand\lbx@finalnamedelim
}
\makeatother
```

Then you can just do

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
```

as you intended to.

Maybe you also want

```
\restorecommand\lbx@finallistdelim
```

if you intend to change `\finallistdelim`.