# Biblatex: customizing existing style

Tags: biblatex, chemistry, spanish

I'm using the `acs-chem` style in `biblatex`, writing in Spanish.

I'm trying to change the "y" that appears before the last author in the bibliography for a ";", like if it wasn't the last one.

I tried `\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{;}` and also this, but neither of them work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[
style=chem-acs,
maxnames=10,
minnames=10
]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot};
and = {;}
}
\renewcommand{\andothersdelim}{; }
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{aksin} ipsum \autocite{baez/article}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343107/finalnamedelim-is-not-working-in-biblatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `\finalnamedelim` to work normally, you need to disable `biblatex`'s smart and feature for Spanish by setting the value of `smartand` to `0`. I think this will disable it in all lists though.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[
  style=chem-acs,
  maxnames=10,
  minnames=10
]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
}
\setcounter{smartand}{0}
\renewcommand*{\andothersdelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{aksin} ipsum \autocite{baez/article}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: So it was a problem of the language. You also put the `\andothersdelim` the proper way. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielÁlvarez, no worries. As an aside, you should separate bibliography string definitions with a comma not a semicolon in `\DefineBibliographyStrings`.